# "Procedure expects parameter which was not supplied" I DID SUPPLY

Tags: c#, sql

I'm getting this error when trying to update a row in DB through stored procedure

> Procedure or Function 'sp_A_Update' expects parameter '@Misc', which was not supplied.

but I HAVE supplied it with this:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Misc", inspection.Misc);
```

Here is my whole code with other parameters taken out to shorten

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_Agent_Inspection_Update", new SqlConnection (Configuration.ConnectionString)))
{
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo = inspection.GetType().GetProperties();

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Misc", inspection.Misc);
    (lots of other params here...)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RepairNotes", inspection.RepairNotes);

    // OPEN CONNECTION
    command.Connection.Open();

    // EXECUTE QUERY
    int rowsAffected =  command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    command.Connection.Close();
    return Boolean.Parse(rowsAffected.ToString());
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Error says "sp_A_Update" but code says "sp_Agent_Inspection_Update". Are you sure you're debugging the right code?

Comment: I don't see you defining `inspection` anywhere. Could be my nonexistant knowledge of C#, but maybe you need to define it?

Comment: Can you post at least part of the stored procedure?

Comment: I would assume the SQL in sp_Agent_Inspection_Update executes sp_A_Update, which is not having the parameter @Misc passed to it.

Comment: I seem to remember that you need to make sure that you are adding the parameters in your code in the same order they appear in the SQL stored procedure definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the obvious mistake about the name of the stored procedure you are calling.

> The easiest way to identify and resolve this issue is to run SQL
>   Profiler. Take a trace while you are executing the code and see what
>   your passing into SQL and you'll see what it expects.